# Recommended books on JB-algebra

Tags: book-recommendation, operator-algebras, jordan-algebras

I want to find a self-contained book on [JB-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_operator_algebra), just like Murphy's book on C*-algebra. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: What is a JB algebra?

Comment: @Aweygan https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_operator_algebra

Answer (score 0):

I really like the book *Jordan operator algebras* by Hanche-Olsen and Størmer. It completely builds the theory of Jordan theories from the ground up (including MacDonalds theorem and the coordinatization theorems for finite-dimensional formally real algebras). Although it proves some results for JB-algebras, it is primarily interested in JBW-algebras though.